# Instances lose autowired properties when static getter is used

Tags: java, spring, collections, dependency-injection, static-methods

I have a problem with autowired properties in my Java classes. I have a factory, that has a `Map<Integer, MyClass>` of MyClass objects. MyClasses have a projectId as propterty and that is how I'd like to get them from the factory. But when the `public static MyClassFactory getInstance()` and `public MyClassInterface createMyClass` are used, the autowired properties in MyClasses are null when retrieved like this, but were not null when inserted into the map.

I would like to know why this happens and how to avoid this.

Besides that, the scope of MyClass is set to prototype, but I am not sure if this will work with this factory as intended. Any idea if this works or how to enforce this behavior?

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public class MyClassFactory {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    private static volatile MyClassFactory instance = null;
    private final HashMap<Integer, MyClass> classMap;

    private MyClassFactory() throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        this.classMap = new HashMap<Integer, MyClassInterface>();
        this.registerMyClasses();
    }

    private void registerMyClasses() throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        registerMyClass(beanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class));
        registerMyClass(beanFactory.getBean(MyClass2.class));
        ...
    }

    private void registerMyClass(MyClassInterface myClassInterface) throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        for (int projectId : myClassInterface.getProjectIds()) {
            if (classMap.containsKey(projectId)) {
                throw new MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException(classMap.get(projectId).getClass().getName());
            }
            classMap.put(projectId, myClassInterface);
        }
    }

    public static MyClassFactory getInstance() throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        MyClassFactory result = instance;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized (MyClassFactory.class) {
                result = instance;
                if (result == null) {
                    instance = result = new MyClassFactory();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public MyClassInterface createMyClass(int projectId) throws NoMyClassRegisteredException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        if (classMap.containsKey(projectId)) {
            return classMap.get(projectId).create();
        }
        throw new NoMyClassRegisteredException("for projectId: " + projectId);
    }

}
```

(If I did not put enough information in here, please tell me and I'll add more.)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing here Singleton pattern with Spring singleton bean. You should avoid this.

EDIT:

Why can't you just use it as Spring singleton bean?:

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public class MyClassFactory {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    private final HashMap<Integer, MyClass> classMap;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        this.classMap = new HashMap<Integer, MyClassInterface>();
        this.registerMyClasses();
    }

    private void registerMyClasses() throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        registerMyClass(beanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class));
        registerMyClass(beanFactory.getBean(MyClass2.class));
        ...
    }

    private void registerMyClass(MyClassInterface myClassInterface) throws MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException {
        for (int projectId : myClassInterface.getProjectIds()) {
            if (classMap.containsKey(projectId)) {
                throw new MyClassAlreadyRegisteredException(classMap.get(projectId).getClass().getName());
            }
            classMap.put(projectId, myClassInterface);
        }
    }

    public MyClassInterface createMyClass(int projectId) throws NoMyClassRegisteredException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        if (classMap.containsKey(projectId)) {
            return classMap.get(projectId).create();
        }
        throw new NoMyClassRegisteredException("for projectId: " + projectId);
    }

}
```

And than you can Autowire this bean into any Spring driven class. **But there is still problem of thread safety on your local variable classMap**. You should tacke that one by passing it around and getting rid of intermediate class level field. If you need cache in singleton bean, you need to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use a factory here properly?